# bridge table joined table have both the keys equal to both the keys

Tags: postgresql, join, where

```
SELECT DISTINCT i0.id,
            i0.name
FROM main_table AS i0
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN "bridge_table" AS i3 ON i3."main_table_id" = i0."id"
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN "other_table" AS r4 ON i3."other_table_id" = r4."id"
```

I need to get records for which other_table has name equal to both "name_1" and "name_2" or name is equal to "name_3". I have tried `WHERE (r4."name" = ANY (name_1, name_2)) OR (r4."name" = name_3)`. it is many to many relation

I know its wrong query...
Any help will be really appreciated, thanks

Update:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table
(
      id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE other_table
(
      id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE bridge_table
(
      other_table_id INT NOT NULL
              REFERENCES other_table,


      main_table_id  INT NOT NULL
              REFERENCES main_table,

      PRIMARY KEY (other_table_id, main_table_id)
);


INSERT INTO main_table(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Main 1');

INSERT INTO main_table(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Main 2');

INSERT INTO main_table(id, name) VALUES (3, 'Main 3');



INSERT INTO other_table(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Other 1');

INSERT INTO other_table(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Other 2');

INSERT INTO other_table(id, name) VALUES (3, 'Other 3');


INSERT INTO bridge_table(other_table_id, main_table_id) VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO bridge_table(other_table_id, main_table_id) VALUES (1, 2);

INSERT INTO bridge_table(other_table_id, main_table_id) VALUES (2, 2);

INSERT INTO bridge_table(other_table_id, main_table_id) VALUES (3, 2);

SELECT mt.id     as mt_id,
      mt.name   as mt_name,
      ot_1.name as ot_1_name,
      ot_2.name as ot_2_name,
      ot_3.name as ot_3_name
FROM main_table AS mt
            INNER JOIN bridge_table AS bt_1 ON bt_1.main_table_id = mt.id
            INNER JOIN other_table AS ot_1 ON bt_1.other_table_id = ot_1.id

            INNER JOIN bridge_table AS bt_2 ON bt_2.main_table_id = mt.id
            INNER JOIN other_table AS ot_2 ON bt_2.other_table_id = ot_2.id

            INNER JOIN bridge_table AS bt_3 ON bt_3.main_table_id = mt.id
            INNER JOIN other_table AS ot_3 ON bt_3.other_table_id = ot_3.id
WHERE (ot_1.name = 'Other 1' AND ot_2.name = 'Other 2')
  OR (ot_3.name = 'Other 3')
```

I have created above sql to help generate required structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the task correctly, then look for

```sql
SELECT mt.id, mt.name
FROM main_table AS mt
JOIN bridge_table AS bt ON bt.main_table_id = mt.id
JOIN other_table AS ot ON bt.other_table_id = ot.id
GROUP BY mt.id, mt.name
HAVING 2 = COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN ot.name IN ('Other 1', 'Other 2') THEN ot.name END )
    OR 1 = COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN ot.name IN ('Other 3')            THEN ot.name END )
```

To make it dynamic use

```sql
-- constant part
HAVING 1 = 0 
-- dynamic parts
    OR (cnt_1 = COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN ot.name IN ( list_1 ) THEN ot.name END ))
    OR (cnt_2 = COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN ot.name IN ( list_2 ) THEN ot.name END ))
-- ...
```

where `list_N` - values list, and `cnt_N` - unique values count in the list.

Comment: it worked like a magic. thank you. it would be great if you can explain last constant and dynamic parts(maybe how/when *Having* works with *OR* ...). I have never seen this clever query/solution...

Comment: @RadioActive `1=0` is always false, so only dynamic conditions may cause that some records will be returned. `OR` defines that the record matched at least one dynamic condition will be returned. Dynamic conditions compares the values count in the list and the values count matched the group (all records which have values not in list produces NULL which is ignored by `COUNT` function).